# How to write encrypted zip archives with Perl

Tags: perl, encryption, zip, expect

I want to send confidential information to recipients who might be not too technical people and won't be able to use GnuPG or other sophisticated encryption technology. So it was defined that sending encrypted Zip files is considered secure™. Zip files are preferred because Microsoft Windows supports that out of the box starting from XP.

Unfortunately [`Archive::Zip`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Zip) from CPAN doesn't support *writing* encrypted archives.

How can we write encrypted Zip files with Perl?

Comment: How are you transferring your zip files? Can I suggest looking at an https webserver? That way you don't have to worry as much because your data is encrypted in flight. (And in certain circumstances, you can do https with client side certificates, which gives you strong auth/encryption, without needing too much tech savvy).

Comment: @Sobrique: information is to be sent via e-mail. There is no encryption method for e-mail that is widespread enough. Instead text is stored in the encrypted Zip file and that is attached to the e-mail.

Comment: Send https link in email, require them to fetch from a webserver?

Comment: Yes, that would be actually possible. But this question wasn't meant to discuss the general approach. It was decided on my client's side. I just didn't find a module for Perl and wanted to share the solution. Everyone is free to chose encrypted Zip files or something else:-)

Comment: @Sobrique: After all please mind that the password for the encrypted containers is transferred independently from the e-mail. Sending an HTTPS link via e-mail would allow everybody with access to the e-mail transfer or inbox to get the confidential information!

Comment: Web servers support authentication too.

Comment: @Sobrique: That's true. But the information sent is a list of passwords to access another system. The passwords are not stored on the server side. When you mentioned HTTPS links I thought of granting access to the remote site to clients with a URL token. Providing a stored password after authenticating via HTTPS is not an option. The token needs to securely included in the original e-mail. With that in mind an encrypted Zip is not that bad, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find a way using any Perl Zip library directly. So I was up to remote controlling the command line `zip` utility. The best way to do that seems to be [`Expect`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect) from CPAN.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Expect;

`touch foo`;

my $zip = Expect->new;
$zip->raw_pty(1);       # behave more like a pipe, disable echoing
$zip->log_stdout(0);    # don't print out from `zip`
$zip->spawn(qw<zip --encrypt foo.zip foo>);

my $password = "secret";
my $timeout  = 1;

for ( 1 .. 2 ) {

    # don't use a regex ref like qr/foo/ but a string like q/foo/ or 'foo'!
    $zip->expect( $timeout, -re => q/password:/ )
      or die "zip didn't ask for password";
    $zip->send( $password, "\n" );
}

my $success = $zip->expect( $timeout, -re => q/foo \((deflated|stored) / );

$zip->soft_close;

print $success ? "success" : "fail", "\n";
```

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the 7-Zip stand-alone utility `7za.exe`. It allows the whole thing to be done in a single command `7za a -tzip -psecret foo.zip foo`

Comment: @Borodin: I was especially looking for a solution that doesn't expose the password in the process list. Passing a secret like a password on the command line is a really bad idea.

Comment: Okay, but it isn't any safer to pass it as a separate string in reponse to a prompt from `zip`. Nothing short of `ssh` will help you here if you have to work with a remote system.

Comment: @Borodin: I've thought about your comment a for a while now and really don't get your point. The question is about creating a file on the local machine. I made sure the password is can't be seen by other local processes in the process list as it happens when passed as command line argument. Doing this on a remote machine is a completely different story but perfectly possible e.g. by piping everything through SSH that you mention. So actually SSH is not necessary but if you bring up remote execution it's the solution. What was your point then then?